# Failed to connect GethNode to external GethNode

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

i want to connect a local Geth-instance to my private Ethereum Network on a ubuntu Server.

System information

Geth version: `1.8.12`
OS & Version: Ubuntu 18.4

Expected behaviour

the local Geth-node is non-miner-node and i would like to send through this node transactions to my private-network (consists of Geth-Nodes) on my server.

Actual behaviour

`net.peerCount` of my local GethNode returns 0

Steps to reproduce the behaviour

I use the bootnode to connect all nodes as seen on the `--bootnode`-flag
Run Server Geth-node:

`geth --datadir "./ethnode1" --networkid 2061 --port 30304  --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3" --ipcpath "./ethnode1/geth.ipc" --mine --minerthreads 1 --gasprice "10000" --etherbase 0xa17ae57bfb4a63b8cbd0c79bc74440791a2a6115 --verbosity 3 --bootnodes "enode://08622fab0c0b4f6268976eb8678ae4bc72271d726825d4a8a60034a7436ae199081294c4c35875a2ca65e8f2bfee3e7d26f727d96a39815d523b150805aff913@server-ip:30301"` 

 
`geth --datadir "./ethnode2" --networkid 2061 --port 30305  --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcport 8546 --rpcapi="db,eth,net,web3,personal,web3" --ipcpath "./ethnode2/geth.ipc" --mine --minerthreads 1 --gasprice "10000" --etherbase 0x6451cb262925d2ad23747240035f52e1a5e3f1d3 --verbosity 3 --bootnodes "enode://08622fab0c0b4f6268976eb8678ae4bc72271d726825d4a8a60034a7436ae199081294c4c35875a2ca65e8f2bfee3e7d26f727d96a39815d523b150805aff913@erver-ip:30301"` 

Run local Geth-node:
 
`geth --datadir "./localnode" --networkid 2061 --ws --wsaddr externalip --rpc --rpcaddr externalip  --rpccorsdomain "*" --wsapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --rpcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --bootnodes "enode://08622fab0c0b4f6268976eb8678ae4bc72271d726825d4a8a60034a7436ae199081294c4c35875a2ca65e8f2bfee3e7d26f727d96a39815d523b150805aff913@serverip:30301"`

`[backtrace]`

Comment: I tried admin.addPeer("enode://enodekey@serverip:port") but i doesn't connect the geth-node on my pc to the geth-nodes on my server...

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the logs and i discovered that i had different versions of my genesis-file.